# C++ json extract a value using key

Tags: c++, json

I found [this](https://github.com/sheredom/json.h) single header c++ repo for parsing JSON, before I explain what is wrong the code below simply makes a request to the website and receives data as json now the goal is to extract the public ip address from the json data

```
std::string convertToString(char* a, int size, int cut)
{
    int i;
    std::string s = "";
    for (i = 0; i < cut; i++) {
        s = s + a[i];
    }
    return s;
}



std::string what_hardware() {
    char buffer[MAX_LEN];
    DWORD read;
    int cut; 
                                      // user agent 
    HINTERNET hSession = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG,NULL,NULL,0);
    HINTERNET conn = InternetOpenUrl(hSession,"https://ifconfig.me/all.json",NULL,0,INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD,0);
    InternetReadFile(conn, buffer, sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(buffer[0]), &read);
    InternetCloseHandle(hSession);
    //cout << buffer << endl;
    
    // this for loop is to detect when is } to ignore the rest of the buffer
    for( int i =0; i < MAX_LEN; i++)
    {
        if (buffer[i] == *"}")
        {
            cut = i;
            break;
        }
    } 
    return convertToString(buffer , sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]) , cut+1 );
}





int main()
{
    std::string hardware = what_hardware();


    struct json_value_s* root = json_parse(hardware.c_str(), strlen(hardware.c_str()));
    assert(root);

    struct json_value_s* ip_addr = json_value_as_object(root)->start->value;
    assert(ip_addr);

    struct json_value_s* extracted = json_extract_value(ip_addr);

    cout << ip_addr << endl;
}
```

I can't really understand how to use the repo to extract any values from any JSON strings
how do I access values so that I can create a variable and give it the value of the ip_address

Comment: The interface of that library looks somewhat crude. Maybe pick a more established library, e.g. https://github.com/nlohmann/json ? If you insist on using this library, their readme has a bunch of examples of how to access the fields.

Comment: Looking at the example code in the link, `cout << ip_addr << endl;` should be `cout << ip_addr->value << endl;`

Comment: @NathanOliver tried your example and it does not work